# Style individual Labels on Gantt-Rows in a VCL TeeChart

Tags: delphi, teechart

I am using TeeChart (Build 2020.30.200525) in a Delphi XE3 VCL-Application.

In that application I am setting up a Gantt series and I would like to style an individual row label on the left axis to set it apart from the others.

Something like changing the color or font-style of the label or highlighting it by using a background.

How could I achieve this?

I have found the `OnGetAxisLabel` event which I ca use to change the text of the labels.

And I have also tried `Axes.Left.Items`, but that only has a single element even after I have added several Values to the Gantt-Series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to force a chart repaint to populate the axis items. Ie:

```pascal
uses VclTee.GanttCh;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Chart1.AddSeries(TGanttSeries).FillSampleValues;

  Chart1.Draw; // Force a repaint to populate Axis Items

  Chart1.Axes.Left.Items.Automatic:=False;
  Chart1.Axes.Left.Items[2].Format.Font.Color:=clRed;
end;
```

Comment: That was very helpful.

I had to set the left axis to "all labels visible" because I have too many Gantt-Items in the chart and it thus decided to create less Axis.Items than the series had values.

It works that way but I will have to think about scrolling/paging next.

Comment: You can recalculate the labels you want to show at the `OnZoom` and `OnUndoZoom` events to fit the new scales